# How do I change my map's font to Noto Kufi Arabic?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker, mapbox-gl-draw

I have a native app that uses Mapbox, my app is mainly for Kurdish customers.
I have a really big problem, the texts and addresses shown on the app use a font that displays the Kurdish texts poorly, I like to make the map show all texts and addresses using [Noto Kufi Arabic](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#kufi-arab) font or any other font I like.

**But how do I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

You can customise your style in Mapbox Studio by replacing the font to your liking, then publish your new style and use it in your app.